# IIS8 MVC .net4 application slow on

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis-7.5

Hello and thank you very much for any suggestions.

I have a C#.NET 4.0 MVC application hosted on Windows2012 Server IIS8 (although the same issue can be replicated on W2008R2 and IIS7.5).

Every new session takes about 10 seconds to load.
This is NOT related to "idle timeout". My idle timeout is set to 120 minutes.
I open Chrome and IE, go to the logout page in one browser, and it takes 10 seconds.
Once the page is loaded (I assume the application is compiled etc) I go to the same page using IE - and it takes 10 seconds. If I refresh the page - I get it back in about 1 second, as is the case with any subsequent pages. If I close the browser and start it again without delay - hitting the first page will, again, take 10 seconds.
I've been trying it on the localhost, to eliminate network related delays.

I did try to "monitor" IIS using

```
 C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list requests
  REQUEST "fb0000048000c8d0" (url:GET /logout, time:9828 msec,   client:fe80::4e6:dd83:6fd2:c1f8%12, stage:AcquireRequestState, module:Detector)
```

I can see that the Worker Process takes the most time to execute.
I am using the "logout"-page as it is not secured. Web.config here reads

```
  <location path="logout">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Finally in my Controller I introduced debug prints and replicated them on the cshtml page:

```
2013-04-30 13:09:48,784 [56] ERROR [(null)] <(null)> - Start Controller
2013-04-30 13:09:48,842 [56] ERROR [(null)] <(null)> - Return view in  Controller
```

output on the View:
    30/04/2013 13:09:50

which makes me believe that the execution of the controller and rendering of the View are not what's causing the delay.

Any ideas or comments are highly welcome and most appreciated. Apologies if there is any information missing.

Comment: Are you opening a data connection on each session?

Comment: Hi George, I am indeed opening a data connection, just looked at SQL profiler: the connection is opened 200ms before I get the "Start Controller" in my log - RPC:Completed exec sp_reset_connection  EntityFrameworkMUE SYSTEM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 0 0 0 0 9908 59 2013-04-30 14:36:37.650 2013-04-30 14:36:37.650 0X00000000000000002600730070005F00720065007300650074005F0063006F006E006E0065006300740069006F006E00 
Audit Login -- network protocol: LPC  -- followed by all the necessary queries - so something takes time before that :s